# OpenGL: Text is not displaying after drawing rectangle

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm working on designing a scale. In that I need to have number displayed in white colour. Currently in the below code, Im trying to display only "825". After that I try to draw a rectangle box with grey color to have the background of the scale. But when I try to execute, I dont see the number ("825, in the below example) is not visible. Only grey rectangle is visible.

```
#define SPD_SCALE_TAPE_STATIC_LINE_COLOR_160        160        // Light GRAY
#define SPD_SCALE_TAPE_STATIC_LINE_COLOR_120        120        // Light GRAY
#define SPD_SCALE_TAPE_STATIC_LINE_COLOR_180        180        // Light GRAY
#define SPD_SCALE_TAPE_STATIC_LINE_COLOR_050        50        // Light GRAY

// Co-ordinates for GRAY box
#define SPD_SCALE_TAPE_GRAY_X1    -8.0
#define SPD_SCALE_TAPE_GRAY_Y1    0.5
#define SPD_SCALE_TAPE_GRAY_X2    -6.0
#define SPD_SCALE_TAPE_GRAY_Y2    6.3

// Method to draw the text with TIMES NEW ROMAN with FONT size = 24
void drawText_TIMES_24(float x, float y, float z, char* text)
{

    int i_len = 0;

    i_len = strlen(text);

    if( i_len > 0)
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        glRasterPos3f(x,y,z);

        while( *text != '\0' )
        {
        if( i_len == 2 )
        {
            glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, ' ');
            i_len = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, *text);
            text = text+1;
         }
       }
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}


void drawAir_Speed_ReadOut_Val(void)
{
    char a[] = "825";
    glColor3ub(0, 255, 0);

    drawText_TIMES_24(-7.5, 3.0, 0.0, a);

}

// Method to draw Spd Scale Tape Gray Rect
void drawSpd_Scale_Tape_Gray_Rect(void)
{
    glColor3ub(SPD_SCALE_TAPE_STATIC_LINE_COLOR_050,     SPD_SCALE_TAPE_STATIC_LINE_COLOR_050, SPD_SCALE_TAPE_STATIC_LINE_COLOR_050);

// Draw TOP rectangle GRAY box
    glRectf(SPD_SCALE_TAPE_GRAY_X1, SPD_SCALE_TAPE_GRAY_Y1, SPD_SCALE_TAPE_GRAY_X2, SPD_SCALE_TAPE_GRAY_Y2);

// Draw BOTTOM rectangle GRAY box
glRectf(-6.0, -0.5, -8.0, -6.3);

// Draw TOP triangle GRAY box
drawTriangle (-6.5, 0.5, -6.0, 0.0, -6.0, 0.5);

// Draw BOTTOM triangle GRAY box
drawTriangle (-6.5, -0.5, -6.0, 0.0, -6.0, -0.5);

}

void draw(void)
{
  drawAir_Speed_ReadOut_Val();
  drawSpd_Scale_Tape_Gray_Rect();
}
```

Comment: Maybe your gray rect is overwriting the text. Try commenting out the gray rect call, do you see any text then? If so then switch order of the calls.

Comment: @Ville I commented and verified. Text is displaying. But, I need the grey background.

Comment: Draw the text after the gray rectangle then, and maybe glDisable (GL_DEPTH_TEST)?

Comment: @Ville Krumlinde thanks for your help. I added glDisable (GL_DEPTH_TEST) before drawing the text. Now I can see the text with the GREY background.

Answer (score 0):

Just speculation - Are you calling glRasterPos3f() before the first glPushMatrix() inside drawText_TIMES_24()? If that's the case maybe you should consider calling glTranslatef() instead of doing the extra glRasterPos3f()?

Comment: glPushMatrix(); glRasterPos3f(x,y,z); is the way i call in drawText_TIMES_24() method.

Comment: In the drawText_TIMES_24() I call
    glPushMatrix();
    glRasterPos3f(x,y,z);